# URL parsing and rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url

Im trying to configure a CMS to run on my computer so i can modify it. I have worked hard to configure it and make sure it builds. Its not my code so its difficult for me to understand it. The application builds with no errors and it is connected to the database.

I can get to the admin section with no problems, but when i try to view the default page i get an 404 error. The global.asax is parsing the URL and trying to get something from an XML. Im not familiar with this technique of building up the content, so i am asking for help to get the site to work so i can add the functions i am suppose to add.

Here is the code that parses the URL

```
   Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT").ToString = "NV32ts" Then Response.End()

    Dim webben As HttpApplication = DirectCast(s, HttpApplication)

    'webben.Response.Write(webben.Request.Path & "<br />")

    'webben.Response.Write(m_Context.Request.ApplicationPath)
    'webben.Response.End()

    'webben.Response.Write(webben.Server.MapPath(webben.Request.ApplicationPath & "/sitemap.xml"))
    'webben.Response.End()

    Dim incomingUrl As String = webben.Request.Url.ToString.ToLower.Trim

    If incomingUrl.IndexOf("fckeditor") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    If incomingUrl.IndexOf("admin") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    If incomingUrl.IndexOf(".axd") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    If incomingUrl.IndexOf(".asmx") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    If incomingUrl.IndexOf("checkoutpayment.aspx") > -1 Then Exit Sub


    'Nytt som rensar bort sidan, för att komma till rätta med 1.asp som istället kan vara pa-gang.aspx
    Dim inc As String = incomingUrl
    If inc.IndexOf(".asp") > 0 Then inc = inc.Substring(0, inc.IndexOf(".asp"))
    If inc.EndsWith("/1") Then inc = inc.Substring(0, inc.Length - 2)
    'inc = inc.Replace("/1.aspx", "")
    'inc = inc.Replace(".aspx", "")


    Dim pieces As String() = incomingUrl.Split("/")
    'Dim lastPiece As String = pieces(pieces.GetUpperBound(0) - 1) 'Egentligen näst sista: pa-gang
    Dim lastPiece As String = pieces(pieces.GetUpperBound(0)) 'Den absolut sista istället, eftersom jag rensar bort ovan

    ' End if following
    'If incomingUrl.IndexOf("webresource.axd") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    'If incomingUrl.IndexOf("jsdebug") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    'If incomingUrl.IndexOf("adminlanguages") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    'If incomingUrl.IndexOf("adminmenus") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    'If incomingUrl.IndexOf("adminpages") > -1 Then Exit Sub
    'If lastPiece = "admin" Then Exit Sub
    ' ----------------

    Dim start As String = ""
    start = pieces(0) & "/" & pieces(1) & "/" & pieces(2)
    If pieces(2) = "localhost" Then start &= "/" & pieces(3)

    Dim outgoingUrl As String = ""
    Dim template As String = ""
    Dim lang As String = ""
    Dim menus As String = ""
    Dim page As String = ""


    'Fix för att xml-filernas länkar ska fungera
    If incomingUrl.Contains("~") Then
        Dim tmp() As String = incomingUrl.Split("~")
        webben.Response.Redirect(start & tmp(1), True)
    End If


    Dim xmlpath As String = inc.Replace(start, "")
    'xmlpath = .Replace("/" & pieces(pieces.GetUpperBound(0)), "")

    If xmlpath.EndsWith("/") Then
        xmlpath.Substring(0, xmlpath.Length - 1) 'Ta bort ev avslutande /
    End If
    If xmlpath = "/" Then xmlpath = ""


    If xmlpath = "" Then Exit Sub


    Dim doc As New XmlDocument
    Dim path As String = webben.Server.MapPath("~/_uploads/sitemap.xml")
    doc.Load(path)


    'Fix för numeriska namn, släng på en _ i början för att funka i xml-filen
    Dim tmpPathParts() As String = xmlpath.Split("/")
    Dim tmpPath As String = "" '/"
    For i As Integer = 0 To tmpPathParts.GetUpperBound(0)
        If tmpPathParts(i).Length > 0 Then tmpPath &= "/"
        If tmpPathParts(i).Length > 0 AndAlso IsNumeric(tmpPathParts(i).Substring(0, 1)) Then
            tmpPath &= "_" & tmpPathParts(i)
        Else
            tmpPath &= tmpPathParts(i)
        End If
    Next
    'Response.Write(tmpPath & "<br />")
    'Response.Write(xmlpath & "<br />")
    'Response.End()

    xmlpath = tmpPath


    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(lastPiece)
    Dim parent As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/root" & xmlpath) ' nodes(0)
    'KAN OVANSTÅENDE FUNGERA? TESTA!

    If parent Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    While Not (parent Is Nothing)
        If parent.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Document Then Exit While
        If parent.Attributes("rootid") Is Nothing Then
            'Response.Write("Value: " & parent.ToString & "<br />")
            'Response.Write("Att: " & parent.Attributes("id").Value & "<br />")
            'Response.Write("sad: " & parent.LocalName & "<br />")

            If Not parent.Attributes("langid") Is Nothing Then
                lang = parent.Attributes("langid").Value
            ElseIf Not parent.Attributes("menuid") Is Nothing Then
                If menus <> "" Then
                    menus &= ","
                End If

                menus &= parent.Attributes("menuid").Value
            Else
                page = parent.Attributes("pageid").Value
            End If

            If template = "" Then
                template = parent.Attributes("template").Value
            End If

        End If

        parent = parent.ParentNode
    End While

    outgoingUrl = template & "?l=" & lang & "&m=" & menus & "&p=" & page

    'Response.Write(m_Context.Request.ApplicationPath & "/" & outgoingUrl)
    'Response.End()

    webben.Context.RewritePath(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath & "/" & outgoingUrl, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @jadarnel27. But i dont quite get it. Is honesty a problem in this forum? :P